# What docker's image do you recomend for production, php or php-alpine?

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I'm setting up a server php with docker. I want to know what image is better for production environment, PHP or PHP-ALPINE.

PHP-ALPINE is more lightweight, but I interest performance and strong.

Comment: How often do you plan to deploy your image and to how many nodes?  The benefit of Alpine images is that they carry a very low disk storage footprint.  This is handy if you're deploying new versions of a derived image very often, or to a cluster composed of a lot of nodes.

Comment: How complex is your build system and library stack?  The downside of Alpine images is that they use lighter-weight alternate versions of some tools like the shell and the system C library.  If you need to install GNU libc and bash, and especially if you're installing a full C toolchain in your runtime image, Alpine won't bring much practical benefit.